# IllegalArgumentException con JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Tengo este problema:

SELECT monthname(h.i_date) AS m FROM History h where year(now()) GROUP BY month(h.i_date)

ejecuto esta sentencia en mysql y no hay problemas.
Pero utilizando JPA en java lanza el sgte error:

[33, 34] The SELECT clause has 'monthname' and '(h.iDate) AS m' that are not separated by a comma.
[70, 88] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.
[102, 103] The GROUP BY clause has 'month' and '(h.iDate)' that are not separated by a comma.

Ojala me puedan ayudar. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que en JPA para llamar las funciones que posee el motor debes usar FUNC() en la consulta, por ejemplo:

```
FUNC('MONTHNAME', h.iDate)
```

Esto si usas EclipseLink 2.1, si usas EclipseLink 2.5 seria:

```
FUNCTION('MONTHNAME', h.iDate)
```

Espero esto te ayude.

Comment: Funciona perfecto! Muchas gracias.